# Why is this code saying that there is no value for "callsign" in the JSONData from the FCC API I am using?

Tags: android, json

I am trying to access the FCC API as follows http://data.fcc.gov/lpfmapi/rest/v1/lat/36/long/-119?format=json&secondchannel=true

If you copy that URL you can see that it yields data some of which has a "callsign" designation. I want to return the callsign and frequency and for some reason I am getting an error saying there is no value for callsign. I am very new to JSONData so wondering what I did wrong! Any help would be amazing, thank you for reading!!!

HERE IS MY CODE FOR MAIN ACTIVITY

```
package com.dredaydesigns.radiostationfinder;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Call;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private RadioData mRadioData;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;

    TextView latitudeLabel;
    TextView longitudeLabel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_content);


        double latitude = 32;
        double longitude = -96;
        final RadioData[] mRadioData = new RadioData[1];
        String radioFinderURL = "http://data.fcc.gov/lpfmapi/rest/v1/lat/" + latitude + "/long/" + longitude + "?format=json&secondchannel=true";

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(radioFinderURL)
                .build();
        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                try {
                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    Log.v(TAG,jsonData);
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        mRadioData[0] = getCurrentDetails(jsonData);

                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception Caught: ", e);
                }
                catch(JSONException e){
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception Caught:", e);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private RadioData getCurrentDetails(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject radioData = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String callSign = radioData.getString("callsign");
        Log.i(TAG, "From JSON: " + callSign);

        JSONObject currently = radioData.getJSONObject("frequency");
        RadioData radioFinder = new RadioData();


            return new RadioData();


    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();


    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            latitudeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            longitudeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }


}
```

and here is my code for RadioData.java

```
package com.dredaydesigns.radiostationfinder;

/**
 * Created by Andreas on 8/10/2015.
 */
public class RadioData {
    public String getCallSign() {
        return mCallsign;
    }

    public void setCallSign(String callsign) {
        mCallsign = callsign;
    }

    public double getFrequency() {
        return mFrequency;
    }

    public void setFrequency(double frequency) {
        mFrequency = frequency;
    }

    public int getChannel() {
        return mChannel;
    }

    public void setChannel(int channel) {
        mChannel = channel;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return mLatitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        mLatitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return mLongitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        mLongitude = longitude;
    }

    private String mCallsign;
    private double mFrequency;
    private int mChannel;
    private double mLatitude;
    private double mLongitude;



}
```

and here is my code for activity main XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity"
                android:background="#ffffed">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Find Stations!"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#010101"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/latitudeLabel"
        android:id="@+id/latitudeLabel"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:textColor="#010101"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/longitudeLabel"
        android:id="@+id/longitudeLabel"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/latitudeLabel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="83dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="83dp"
        android:textColor="#010101"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and finally here is what the logcat said, and the first line you can see it is receiving all the data so I guess I am not writing it properly to import the "callsign" value?

```
    08-10 23:13:42.115  28737-28753/com.dredaydesigns.radiostationfinder V/MainActivity﹕ {"status":"OK","responseTime":1777,"message":[],"decision":"PASSED.","interferingAnalysis":[{"channel":221,"frequency":92.1,"interferingChannels":[{"callsign":"KTBB-FM","interferenceChannel":221,"interferenceChannelType":"Same channel (cochannel)","actualDistance":80.1,"minDistanceReqd":119.0}]},{"channel":225,"frequency":92.9,"interferingChannels":[{"callsign":"KRMX","interferenceChannel":225,"interferenceChannelType":"Same channel (cochannel)","actualDistance":132.0,"minDistanceReqd":143.0},{"callsign":"KTYL-FM","interferenceChannel":226,"interferenceChannelType":"First-adjacent channel ","actualDistance":103.1,"minDistanceReqd":111.0}]},{"channel":260,"frequency":99.9,"interferingChannels":[{"callsign":"WACO-FM","interferenceChannel":260,"interferenceChannelType":"Same channel (cochannel)","actualDistance":144.3,"minDistanceReqd":203.0}]},{"channel":264,"frequency":100.7,"interferingChannels":[{"callsign":"KPXI","interferenceChannel":264,"interferenceChannelType":"Same channel (cochannel)","actualDistance":90.6,"minDistanceReqd":119.0},{"callsign":"KWRD-FM","interferenceChannel":264,"interferenceChannelType":"Same channel (cochannel)","actualDistance":187.4,"minDistanceReqd":203.0}]},{"channel":273,"frequency":102.5,"interferingChannels":[{"callsign":"KLJT","interferenceChannel":272,"interferenceChannelType":"First-adjacent channel ","actualDistance":80.1,"minDistanceReqd":84.0},{"callsign":"KBRQ","interferenceChannel":273,"interferenceChannelType":"Same channel (cochannel)","actualDistance":111.3,"minDistanceReqd":178.0}]},{"channel":277,"frequency":103.3,"interferingChannels":[{"callsign":"KJCS","interferenceChannel":277,"interferenceChannelType":"Same channel (cochannel)","actualDistance":128.5,"minDistanceReqd":143.0},{"callsign":"KESN","interferenceChannel":277,"interferenceChannelType":"Same channel (cochannel)","actualDistance":187.4,"minDistanceReqd":203.0}]},{"channel":285,"frequency":104.9,"interferingChannels":[{"callsign":"KZMP-FM","interferenceChannel":285,"interferenceChannelType":"Same channel (cochannel)","actualDistance":187.3,"minDistanceReqd":193.0}]},{"channel":289,"frequency":105.7,"interferingChannels":[{"callsign":"KYKX","interferenceChannel":289,"interferenceChannelType":"Same channel (cochannel)","actualDistance":129.2,"minDistanceReqd":193.0}]},{"channel":298,"frequency":107.5,"interferingChannels":[{"callsign":"KISX","interferenceChannel":297,"interferenceChannelType":"First-adjacent channel ","actualDistance":82.1,"minDistanceReqd":84.0},{"callsign":"KMVK","interferenceChannel":298,"interferenceChannelType":"Same channel (cochannel)","actualDistance":111.5,"minDistanceReqd":178.0}]},{"channel":299,"frequency":107.7},{"channel":300,"frequency":107.9}]}
    08-10 23:13:42.115  28737-28753/com.dredaydesigns.radiostationfinder E/MainActivity﹕ Exception Caught:
        org.json.JSONException: No value for callsign
                at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:38

9)
            at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
            at com.dredaydesigns.radiostationfinder.MainActivity.getCurrentDetails(MainActivity.java:80)
            at com.dredaydesigns.radiostationfinder.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:24)
            at com.dredaydesigns.radiostationfinder.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:63)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:170)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this two line you are getting the value of "callsign" key.

```
JSONObject radioData = new JSONObject(jsonData);
String callSign = radioData.getString("callsign");
```

This is your json data :

```
 //this is the starting of your jsondata means the radioData = this whole data.
 {
 "status": "OK",
 "responseTime": 1819,
 "message": [],
 "decision": "PASSED.",
 "interferingAnalysis": [
 {
  "channel": 222,
  "frequency": 92.3
},
{
  "channel": 239,
  "frequency": 95.7,
  "interferingChannels": [
    {
      "callsign": "KJFX",
      "interferenceChannel": 239,
      "interferenceChannelType": "Same channel (cochannel)",
      "actualDistance": 113.9,
      "minDistanceReqd": 143
    }
  ]
},
{
  "channel": 266,
  "frequency": 101.1,
  "interferingChannels": [
    {
      "callsign": "KWYE",
      "interferenceChannel": 266,
      "interferenceChannelType": "Same channel (cochannel)",
      "actualDistance": 118.1,
      "minDistanceReqd": 143
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

Now check inside the data the callsign key is present inside a jsonobject which is present inside a jsonarray named as "interferingChannels" and this jsonarray is present inside a jsonobject.

Now if you want to get the value of "callsign" key then you need to use this code :

```
JSONObject radioData = new JSONObject(jsonData);
JSONArray jsonArray = radioData.getJSONArray("interferingAnalysis");
for(int i =0; i<jsonArray.size(); i++){
String callSign = radioData.getJsonObject(i).getJSONArraay("interferingChannels").getJSONObject(0).getString("callsign");
}
```

I hope this will work for you. May some spelling needs to be change. Please check that and let me know if you have any problem.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1) Read the JSON (which you're doing)

2) Search down to "interferingAnalysis" (an array of "channel" objects)

3) For each channel...

4) Look for an "interferingChannels" array

5) Each "interferingChannels" element in the array might have a "callsign".

I like this site to "pretty print" JSON (for troubleshooting, to better understand the JSON structure:

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Here is a good tutorial on parsing a "complex" JSON object:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

The example has an array of "contact" objects; each contact has a "Name", "Address"  ... and one or more "phone" sub-objects.

'Hope that helps :)